# how to find a pattern and substitute in vim

Tags: vim

current outlook;

```
P12104001;example_01_01,
P12104002;example_02_01,
P12104003;example_03_01,
P12104004;example_04_01,
```

I want to have;

```
<example_01_01>,
<example_02_01>,
<example_03_01>,
<example_04_01>,
```

Please suggest options using substitute in gvim (so that i can replace strings only in marked regions. example like this `:'a,'b s \*******\<******>`)

Answer (score 4):

To get from

```
P12104001;example_01_01,
P12104002;example_02_01,
P12104003;example_03_01,
P12104004;example_04_01,
```

to this

```
P12104001;example_01_01,
<example_02_01>,
<example_03_01>,
P12104004;example_04_01,
```

use

```
:/002/,/003/s/.*\(example_.._..\)/<\1>/
```

which reads as

```
: Command
 /Start of section/,/End of section/
            s/    substitute
             .*   all chars up to 
                \(string to remember . for wild chars\)
             /<   with 
               \1 put in the remember string
                 >/  rest of replacement.
```

Use :help address in Vim for see other ways of addressing line ranges.

Comment: I do not want to hardcode (002 or 003).

Comment: and what if the entire row looks like  - *ELEMENT, TYPE=S4RS, ELSET=P12104001;example_01_01

Comment: May be better to suggest using visual selection and then perform substitution on selected lines

Comment: row looks like: *ELEMENT, TYPE=S4RS, ELSET=P12104001;example_01_01 and i need *ELEMENT, TYPE=S4RS, ELSET=<example_01_01>      ....currently i am testing :'a,'b s /P........;example_.._../<example_.._..>

Comment: .*  = all chars up to, what is for 'all chars after' ?

Answer (score 0):

Fred Gannett already answered your questions but to answer your comments:

`%s/.*\(example_\d\+_\d\+\).*/<\1>,/`

substitutes in whole file without hardcoding the digits behind "example". If you want to restict range, use visual selection or something like `.,3s/.*\(example_\d\+_\d\+\).*/<\1>,/` (current line up to line three).

You must be sure that every line that contains the regex should get substituted.